# Stored Procedure, adding multiple rows not in a loop

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert two rows into a database that appened onto a larger insert, however when i try to do one after another only the first goes in and the second does not, this is just a portion of the code but its the only part thats bugging so i think it should suffice. the exception is saything im passing to many variables through

```
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("f") = 8 Then
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submission", Session("dfd")) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionNumber", 1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", 0) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionSAnswer", Session("fdd"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testID", Request.QueryString("f"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option", 0) '
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdBy", Session("Username"))
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Dispose()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submission", Session("fgd")) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionNumber", 17)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", 0) l
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionSAnswer", Session("dffdfdf"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testID", Request.QueryString("f"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option", 0) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdBy", Session("Username"))
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

i sloved it by rather than reinnitiating i made extra commands

```
 ElseIf Request.QueryString("f") = 8 Then
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submissionID", Session("SubmissionID"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionNumber", 1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionID", 0)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionSAnswer", Session("matches"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testID", Request.QueryString("f"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionID", 0)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdBy", Session("Username"))
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submissionID", Session("SubmissionID"))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionNumber", 17)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionID", 0)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionSAnswer", Session("dosing2"))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testID", Request.QueryString("f"))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionID", 0)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdBy", Session("Username"))
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: remove the `conn.Dispose()` and try to create a New Instance Connection for new Command, and don't forget close the every connection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can re-open a connection that has been disposed.  Just close it until you are sure that you are really done with it, then dispose it.